# Reactjs - creating a logger screen component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to Reactjs (And using React Native). I created a basic component for debugging purposes - which is a logger screen.

```
  render()
  {
    return (
     return logLines.map(function(line)
     {
       return <Text>{line}</Text>
     }
  )}
```

I was wondering what is a reasonable design for such a logger to have all other components log some information through some api (maybe even override console.log) and for that to be delivered to this component?

I though using Redux.
But not sure in which place I should place the code that override console.log to have it registered into a store.

Thank you

Comment: This is a super broad question. What is that you want to log? Is it something like Redux Devtools: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools?

Comment: redux logger does a good job of logging everything that goes into redux store via reducers. https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger